# Custom Middleware doesn't handle exception with debug run ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, exception, middleware, .net-5

I am trying to use middleware for exception handling in my ASP.Net Core 5.0 project but it doesn't handle the exception and debugging stops the application when exception is thrown.

```
    
public class CustomExceptionMiddleWare
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public CustomExceptionMiddleWare(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            try
            {
                string message = "[Request] HTTP " + context.Request.Method + " - " + context.Request.Path;
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                await _next(context);
                watch.Stop();
                message = "[Request] HTTP " + context.Request.Method + " - " + context.Request.Path + " responded " +
                    context.Response.StatusCode.ToString() + " in " + watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " ms";
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                watch.Stop();
                await HandleException(context, ex, watch);
            }
        }

        private Task HandleException(HttpContext context, Exception ex, Stopwatch watch)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
            context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;


            string message = "[Error]   HTTP" + context.Request.Method + " - " + context.Response.StatusCode +
                " Error Message " + ex.Message + " in " + watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " ms";
            Console.WriteLine(message);


            var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Error = ex.Message }, Formatting.None);
            return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
        }
    }


    public static class CustomExceptionMiddlewareExtension
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseCustomExceptionMiddleWare(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<CustomExceptionMiddleWare>();
        }
    }
}
```

*startup.cs :*

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseCustomExceptionMiddleWare();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "PatikaWebApi v1"));

            }

            
            //app.UseMiddleware<CustomExceptionMiddleWare>();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCustomExceptionMiddleWare();


            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

*controller*

```
 [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IActionResult GetById(int id)
        {
            BookDetailViewModel result;
            GetBooksDetailQuery query = new GetBooksDetailQuery(_context,_mapper);
            query.BookId = id;
            GetBooksDetailQueryValidator validator = new GetBooksDetailQueryValidator();
            validator.ValidateAndThrow(query);
            result = query.Handle();
            return Ok(result);        
        }
```

When the exception is thrown middleware doesn't handle the exception with Debug mode. I searched for the solution and i found one that removing **app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();** row didn't work for me.I have tried to change pipeline but didn't work either. What would be the solution ? Thank you for your attention.

Error is Exception User-Unhandled

Comment: Has this problem been resolved?

Answer (score 2):

on the surface I cannot see why your debug point is not being hit. But I would suggest using a filter instead of middleware for this scenario.

You can look at a article by Jason Taylor on how to do this. Here is his github source code link.

https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/src/WebUI/Filters/ApiExceptionFilterAttribute.cs

I also wrote a simplified example for you. I hope this fixes your problem.

**Exception filter:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;

namespace Multitrust.API.Filters
{
public class ApiExceptionFilter : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public ApiExceptionFilter() 
    {
    }


    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {

        HandleException(context);
    }

    private void HandleException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        //Do stuff with the exception
    }

    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            options.Filters.Add(new ApiExceptionFilter()));
            
      //Bind other services...

     }
```

Let me know if you need any help with this.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

There is already a middleware provided in .NET core. `app.UseExceptionHandler`.
you need to define the response when exception is raised.

I had written a simple article sometime back on same topic.
have a look.

[Handling exceptions in ASP.Net core API](https://medium.com/@niteshsinghal85/how-i-have-handled-exception-globally-in-asp-net-core-api-7b8c2603af72)

hope it solves your issue.